# RealityKit – Remove last AnchorEntity with a button

Tags: swift, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

This is my `func updateUIView()` function.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {

    if let model = self.modelPlaced {
        if let modelEntity = model.modelEntity {
            let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .any)
            let tempEntity = modelEntity.clone(recursive: true)
            anchorEntity.name = "EntityAnchor"
            anchorEntity.addChild(tempEntity)
            uiView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
            tempEntity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            uiView.installGestures([.translation, .rotation, .scale], 
                                     for: tempEntity)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.modelPlaced = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to have my delete button to just delete the recently placed AR object. But I have problems binding the `removeAnchor()` function to the delete button.

```
struct DeleteButtonView: View {

    @Binding var isPlacementEnabled: Bool
    @Binding var selectedModel: Model?

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            //ARView.scene.removeAnchor(anchorEntity)
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "xmark")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact that creating many anchors is not a good idea (it's better to attach several models to one anchor), I suggest removing the last anchor in the collection might look like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    
    @State var arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ARViewContainer(arView: $arView).ignoresSafeArea()

            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Remove the Last Anchor") {
                    let lastIndex = arView.scene.anchors.count - 1
                    
                    if lastIndex > -1 {
                        arView.scene.anchors.remove(at: lastIndex)
                    }
                    print(arView.scene.anchors.count)
                }
                Button("Create New Scene") {
                    let scene = try! Experience.loadBox()
                    arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
                    print(arView.scene.anchors.count)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regular `ARViewContainer` containing `@Binding` property wrapper:

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var arView: ARView
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let scene = try! Experience.loadBox()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(scene)
        print(arView.scene.anchors.count)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ arView: ARView, context: Context) { }
}
```